# Reactstrap modal under an iframe in react.js application

Tags: reactjs, iframe, modal-dialog, reactstrap

I'm making an application in react.js and I have used react-frame-component to create iframe. In that iframe I have written code for Modal (reactstrap). This modal is opening in my application window. I want it to open in that iframe only.

Created relevant issue in reactstrap git repo. Let me know if you know any way to overwrite Modal's document object.
issue: https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/issues/1326

app link: https://q8lp3kyr5w.codesandbox.io/

code : https://codesandbox.io/s/q8lp3kyr5w

Component

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Modal, ModalBody, Button } from "reactstrap";
import Frame from "react-frame-component";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./styles.css";

class ModalComp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      modal: false
    };

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  }

  toggle() {
    this.setState({ modal: !this.state.modal });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Frame>
          <Button onClick={this.toggle}>Toggle Modal</Button>
          <Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle}>
            <ModalBody>
              <br />
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum,
              ipsam? A id numquam inventore, cumque debitis similique eos
              maiores provident? Sed alias odit fuga, repellat ducimus
              voluptatum aliquid quis pariatur?
            </ModalBody>
          </Modal>
        </Frame>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <b>How to open modal in this iframe?</b>
    <ModalComp />
  </div>
);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

css:

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: You should post your code here, not in a third party website that may remove it at some point.

Comment: Did you try writing both `Button` and `Modal` as a single component and using that inside `Frame` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried. I have also looked at reactstrap Modal source code. In source code Modal uses document.body to append modal at the end of body. react-frame-component can provide it's own document object but again we can't pass that to reactstrap's modal. I tried to use reactstrap using cdn in iframe, but couldn't get that working. I think that using cdn script may work, need to try more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, reactstrap don't provide facility to pass document as props. You can use react-modal. See github issue link shared in question.